# Using SublimeText3, how to open all files with the same name

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I had a situation in which I wanted to view all files that were named the same (e.g. all files named `index.js`).

I ended up opening them one at a time...but maybe there's a way I could have opened them all at once...?

**Alternate Strategy**

I did find some searchable term that existed in all those files and this helped identify all the files (at least I hope so) and this seemed slightly easier than repeatedly opening files with `cmd-p`...

Comment: I assume you mean you were in Sublime and wanted to hit a command that would do it versus starting Sublime from a console and opening them?

Comment: is there a way to open all similarly named files with Sublime via the command line?  (because either way works for me)

Comment: Indeed there is; see my answer below. From within Sublime it would still be possible via a plugin, but it's complicated by having to find the appropriate files as the current API doesn't expose the current file index and so you have to resort to a manual `os.walk()` and `fnmatch.fnmatch()` or something similar (and you have to be familiar with Python as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From directly within Sublime there's no method by default that would allow you to open multiple files all at once. It's possible to add that sort of functionality via a plugin/external package. To my knowledge there isn't anything like that currently available on [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/), but there are a lot of packages there and it may well be hiding.

Writing such a plugin is fairly simple overall since Sublime does most of the heavy lifting, but it requires a knowledge of Python. The trickier part would be figuring out what files should be opened.

On the flip side, Sublime ships with a command line helper tool called `subl` that talks to the running copy of Sublime and starts one as needed. Assuming that it's available on your path, opening all of the JavaScript files in a particular folder can be done that way.

```
tmartin:dart:~> subl *.js
```

That would open all of the matching files in the most recently active Sublime window; you can include `-n` to tell Sublime that it should open a new window first and put the files there instead:

```
tmartin:dart:~> subl -n *.js
```

This also works with folders as well as files, which adds the folders to the current window or creates a new window with that folder open.

See `subl --help` for more information on other available options, including opening files at an exact location.

---

[EDIT]

If you're using Linux or MacOS, you can extend this technique to open files in subfolders of the current folder as well, in a couple of different ways.

> ***NOTE:*** The following does not apply to Windows (at least in the standard command prompts) because Windows doesn't expand file globs itself and Sublime has to do this itself, which it can do for simple globs like `*.js` but not for more complex ones that include folders.

If you have a shallow folder structure, you can include multiple terms on the command line. For example, if there is only one directory level deep:

```
tmartin:dart:~> subl -n *.js */*.js
```

If there are two directory levels, you need to include another term to match that due to the shell globbing rules:

```
tmartin:dart:~> subl -n *.js */*.js */*/*.js
```

For anything other than one or two levels this is rather tedious as well as error prone, in which case I would recommend using the `find` utility instead:

```
tmartin:dart:~> subl -n `find . -name '*.js'`
```

Here the `find` command searches the current folder (`.`) for all files with names that match `*.js`, which it does recursively. Once it's done the results are put into a string. Note that it's important to wrap the glob in `'single quotes'` to tell the shell it shouldn't try to expand them itself.

The back ticks around the `find` command tell the shell to execute that first and then use the result as the arguments to the `subl -n` command.

The results of the find operation are relative to the start location, so you could also do something like `find /Users/tmartin/projects/*.js` from anywhere to find all of the appropriate files.

Windows doesn't have a `find` utility that works as this one does, but with a little batch file kung-fu you can create a batch file that does the same sort of thing:

```batch
@ECHO OFF

IF "%~1" == "" GOTO ERROR
subl -n
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a IN (`dir %* /b/s`) DO subl "%%a"

GOTO DONE

:ERROR
ECHO Provide a file glob on the command line.

:DONE
```

This is a bit sub-optimal if there are a lot of files because it requires executing `subl` once for every file to be opened instead of passing them all at once, but I am far from a batch file guru.

Comment: when i run `subl -n *index.js` i get a new sublime window that contains the `index.js` file in the root of the application, but not any of the others (others being more deeply nested)....i tried variances of `subl -n **/*index.js` but no luck...

Comment: `subl -n *index.js */*index.js` should work if you're on MacOS or Linux. On Windows the OS doesn't expand file globs for you and Sublime has to do it manually, and apparently it has issues with the second form, so while `*index.js` would expand, the second one would not. The only way I know around that is to use an alternate command processor like git bash or similar.

Comment: hm...still not getting any deeply nested files from `*/*index.js`  (from MacOS)

Comment: I added some more information on how to do this in my answer.