# How can I open all .html files in subdirectories Sublime Text 3?

Tags: html, windows, command-line, sublimetext3

I have over 6,000 files to edit all in seperate subfolders. I want to edit them all because they are in a different language.

[Image might explain it better :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iArUy.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open all your files at once in SublimeText, the best is probably to open it from the command line using the `subl`command, as I don't think this can be done from the editor itself.

On Linux or MacOS, you could simply use

```
subl -n `find . -name '*.html'`
```

from the `car_detail` folder.

You tagged your question as a Windows question. In that case, next question and answer seem to  detail what you're looking for:
[Using SublimeText3, how to open all files with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52008684/using-sublimetext3-how-to-open-all-files-with-the-same-name) (all credit for my answer comes from that post).